# Standardizing jpeg size in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I am displaying images from the SQL Server database for all the employees.
when these images are stored in the database they were stored with different sizes. One are of smaller size and the other ones of bigger sizes.

When I say size, I mean width and height.

When I display it in aspx page I want to display in 300X250 size

How can I do that? If I set the image control height and width the images are distorted.

Please help

Comment: Just suggesting to save images to the DB in final size from the beginning - its more efficient and easy. Let the user upload a picture, and then make it's width/height max at 300/250, so it's max size is 300x250, but maintain aspect ratio. Fill in black stripes at top/bottom or sides if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at ImageResizer.net. It has everything you need including code samples for SQL Server integration and croping with aspect ratio preserved:

http://imageresizing.net/

The most popular features are free and open-source:

- Resizing, cropping, rotating, flipping
- Borders, drop-shadows, padding, background colors
- Adjustable Jpeg compression. Multi-page tiff viewing
- Animated GIF frame selection. Comprehensive, real-time diagnostics
- Basic GIF and PNG encoding
- Gradient generation

Answer (score 1):

If the image is distorted when you set an 300x250 size, it is probably because the aspect ratio is different. Try setting either width or height.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to your question, you can do a couple of things,

1. You can use an algo to resize images while maintaining the raito between heights. You would need to run it for old images and for every new image. Here's an article to get you started : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13192/Image-Resizing-Maintaining-Height-Width-Ratio
2. You can run a code on all images already stored in database and if bigger then your allowed limits, you can crop them. And place the same cropping mechanism for newly uploaded images.
3. While displaying image, you check the height/width and make them smaller only if it exceeds your desirable limits.

for all approaches, if images have smaller height/width than the ones you want then you would just have to leave them as it is otherwise they will get distorted.

Additionally, I do want to tell you that putting images and for that matter, any other file in database is a bad practice :( It's an overhead on memory. A better practice is to put it in file system, you can google further to find the advantages of that approach.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your HTML, you should specify the actual height and width of the file.

   If you don't, the image will likely be distorted, and/or render with the "jaggies".
2. If you truly want to make an image 300x250, then you'll need to use tools like [The Gimp](http://www.gimp.org), Photoshop or [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) to resize and/or crop it to the desired height and width.