# c# image resizing

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing, imageresizer

Just working on a image uploader/resizer in my asp.net 4 web forms project.  Does anyone know of a technique in C# for resizing uploaded images that could help with ones that are smaller than the minimum size required?

Obviously the quality will be suspect if resizing up the way, so has anyone found a way of possibly creating a new image that is the right size that is maybe plain white and then placing the original image on top of that white background?

Thanks

**Edit** - now ImageResizer.net is working well, but having a job resizing when the image is smaller.  See comment below IrishChieftains answer for full details:

**FINAL EDIT ################**

Ok, I swear I tried this last night and it didn't work, so maybe just needed a clean browser or VS2010 restart but for anyone who's interested, here was my final solution.  The key was `scale=upscalecanvas` :

```
int maxWidth = 400;
int maxHeight = 200;

ImageBuilder.Current.Build(saveLocation, saveLocation, new ResizeSettings("width=" + maxWidth + "&height=" + maxHeight + "&mode=pad&bgcolor=DDDDDD&anchor=middlecenter&scale=upscalecanvas"));
```

Can't rate ImageResizer.net highly enough - great program

Comment: If possible, copy your final edit into an answer so you can mark it as such, for future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best library out there is ImageResizer. If that doesn't help, then you'll end up trying it by hand...

[Standardizing jpeg size in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220781/standardizing-jpeg-size-in-asp-net/10220857#10220857)

Comment: Ah that does look like the thing I'm after.  Will have a go at that and report back.  Thanks

Comment: I've noticed that the quality is also retained which leads me to believe that this will work in e-on's case.

Comment: Ok this is really good - and it pretty much solves my problem apart from one thing:  I've edited my question with the code I have, but if the correct dimensions for the images is 400 X 200 and someone uploads an image that is 50 X 75, I'd like that to sit in the middle of a 400 X 200 canvas at it's original size, but on a grey background - can that be done?  It seems that when the dimensions are lower, it causes problems and either scales it very large, or ignores it altogether

Comment: I'm sure there must be a way: http://imageresizing.net/docs ... Plus there are numerous specialized plugins available. You might also be able to set a larger background using CSS for this scenario?

Comment: yeah i've tried numerous options from the docs but can't seem to crack this last issue.  Great program though, thanks

Comment: Use `&scale=canvas` to center it on a canvas when upscaling.